# how to create breadcrumbs using wordpress nav menu without plugin?

Tags: wordpress

trying to show breadcrumbs but i am stuck.

```
ABOUT US 
 - TEAM
 - WHAT WE DO
```

i don't understand how to show all menus dynamically in breadcrumbs, if i am currently on what we do page then how to show in breadcrumbs kindly help me

i try this

```
<?php $menuID = $post->ID;
query_posts( 'post_type=page&post_parent=$menuID' );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_title();
endwhile;
?>
```

this code just show child of every page but how can i find page which one is clicked

Comment: it's easier to use a plugin who already does that...

Comment: how to do without plugin ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Place this code in `custom_functions.php:`

```
    function the_breadcrumb() {
    global $post;
    echo '<ul id="breadcrumbs">';
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo '<li><a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '">';
        echo 'Home';
        echo '</a></li><li class="separator"> / </li>';
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            echo '<li>';
            the_category(' </li><li class="separator"> / </li><li> ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo '</li><li class="separator"> / </li><li>';
                the_title();
                echo '</li>';
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            if($post->post_parent){
                $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
                $title = get_the_title();
                foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
                    $output = '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($ancestor).'" title="'.get_the_title($ancestor).'">'.get_the_title($ancestor).'</a></li> <li class="separator">/</li>';
                }
                echo $output;
                echo '<strong title="'.$title.'"> '.$title.'</strong>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><strong> '.get_the_title().'</strong></li>';
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (is_tag()) {single_tag_title();}
    elseif (is_day()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F jS, Y'); echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_month()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F, Y'); echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_year()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('Y'); echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_author()) {echo"<li>Author Archive"; echo'</li>';}
    elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) {echo "<li>Blog Archives"; echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_search()) {echo"<li>Search Results"; echo'</li>';}
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Go to your `single.php` page and add the following code anywhere you want to display the breadcrumbs.

```
<?php the_breadcrumb(); ?>
```